# Changing axis ticks labels to months names and expressions in `geom_bar`

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, geom-bar

I am trying to customize a plot for this data.

```
x <- 1:12
z1 <- c("m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n")
z2 <- c("m", "m", "m", "m", "p", "p", "p", "p", "n", "n", "n", "n")
z3 <- c("m", "m", "m", "p", "p", "p", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n")
```

So I created a data frame and plotted it.

```
df <- data.frame(x, z1, z2, z3)
colors <- c("m" = "#f8766d", "n" = "#00BA38", "p" = "#619CFF")

df_long <- pivot_longer(df, cols = c("z1", "z2", "z3"), names_to = "variable", values_to = "value")

df_long$value <- factor(df_long$value, levels = c("m", "n", "p"))

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = variable, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  coord_flip()
```

The output is not bad; it looks like this.

[image]

But we would like to have three ticks on the x-axis as `Jan`, `Feb`, `Mar`. So `Jan` would be where `x=1`, then `Feb` would be where `x=5`and `Mar` would be where `x=9`.

On the y-axis, we would like to have `z(t,1)`, `z(t,2)`, `z(t,3)` but in italic like what we do with `expression()` in labels.

Is it possible to do these? Could someone help please?

Comment: your aim is to change the plot axis appearance ? your current x axis is the projection of the frequency of m, n, p, is there a relation between m, n, p and months .

Comment: Thank you. m,n, and p are just the events that occur each week, and each month has 4 weeks, but there is no connection between frequencies and months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from your plot object `p` you can change and customize tick marks and labels.

As you mentioned `Jan` is placed where `x=1` (1 occurrence of m, n or p ,Feb is placed at 5 occurrence)

```r
p=ggplot(df_long, aes(x = variable, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  coord_flip()
p +  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face="italic")) +
    scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("z1","z2","z3"),
                      labels=c("z(t,1)", "z(t,2)", "z(t,3)"))+
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(1,5,9),
                     labels=c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

x <- 1:12
z1 <- c("m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n")
z2 <- c("m", "m", "m", "m", "p", "p", "p", "p", "n", "n", "n", "n")
z3 <- c("m", "m", "m", "p", "p", "p", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n")

df <- data.frame(x = factor(x), z1, z2, z3) # convert x to a factor

colors <- c("m" = "#f8766d", "n" = "#00BA38", "p" = "#619CFF")

df_long <- pivot_longer(df, cols = c("z1", "z2", "z3"), names_to = "variable", values_to = "value")

df_long$value <- factor(df_long$value, levels = c("m", "n", "p"))

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = variable, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = expression("Jan", "Feb", "Mar")) +
  ylab(expression(italic("z"(t,1:3)))) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face = "italic"))
```

[image]

Do you mean something like this?

Comment: Thank you. We would like to present each row with a `z` so the first row, on the y-axis, has the label `z(t,1)` and so on. On the x-axis, instead of numbers from 1 to 12, we would like to show three months from January to March, starting from `x=1` for January and `x=9` for March.